# jdk sourcecode about AbstractList

Tags: java

I'm reading jdk sourcecode,find some problems:
Why an Object without new can use the method that not static?

```
class SubList<E> extends AbstractList<E> {
private final AbstractList<E> l;
private final int offset;
private int size;

SubList(AbstractList<E> list, int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
    if (fromIndex < 0)
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("fromIndex = " + fromIndex);
    if (toIndex > list.size())
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("toIndex = " + toIndex);
    if (fromIndex > toIndex)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("fromIndex(" + fromIndex +
                                           ") > toIndex(" + toIndex + ")");
    l = list;
    offset = fromIndex;
    size = toIndex - fromIndex;
    this.modCount = l.modCount;
}

public E set(int index, E element) {
    rangeCheck(index);
    checkForComodification();
    return l.set(index+offset, element);
}

public E get(int index) {
    rangeCheck(index);
    checkForComodification();
    return l.get(index+offset);
}
```

why list.size() and l.get() worded?

Comment: "Why an Object without new can use the method that not static"
- Which method are you talking about?
"why list.size() and l.get() worded?" - What do you mean with 'worded'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

size() and get() are indeed non-static methods from AbstractList. `list.size()` and `l.get()` work because they are correctly being invoked from an AbstractList instance (`list` and `l`). That instance is provided as an argument to the constructor of `SubList` and then stored in a private field of the class:

```
private final AbstractList<E> l;
[...]
SubList(AbstractList<E> list, int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
[...]
    l = list;
```

The instance of `AbstractList` must be created (maybe with `new`) at some point before passing it to the constructor of `SubList` as an argument.

Comment: Thx,I understand! It's a simple question,I aways thinking that an object can't use the method without being created.